# Is there an equivalent of optionalChaining in Javascript ES2020?

Tags: javascript, optional-chaining, ecmascript-2020

As we know, ES2020 supports optionalChaining. For example, we can write codes like:
let x = {a:{b:'c'}};
console.log(x?.a?.b);
and we will get 'c'.

But in some cases, we may want to use the expression like x[a][b] rather than x.a.b. Can we use  something like x?[a]?[b] to evaluate the validation of each chained object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is the same for [brackets notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#Optional_chaining_with_expressions):

```
 x?.[a]?.[b]
```

Example:

```js
const x = {a:{b:'c'}};
const a = 'a';
const b = 'b';

const result = x?.[a]?.[b];

console.log(result);
```